# On-premises usages of LUIS.ai

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Can LUIS.ai be run on the edge (on-premises)?  We have issues with consistent internet connectivity within our specific use-case and can't provide high QOS without an on-premises model.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Luis relies on several APIs and a published web app in Azure, Internet connectivity could be an issue in implementing it. A suggestion i'd provide would be to create a bot ran locally, then use the programmatic API:

> LUIS provides a programmatic API that does everything that the UI at https://www.luis.ai does. This can save time when you might have a lot of preexisting data and it'd be faster to create a LUIS app programmatically than by entering information by hand.

More Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-tutorial-node-import-utterances-csv)

Comment: Adam, this is great info thanks.  However, we need a local instance of LUIS.ai.  Our issue is that every element of the cog services arch needs to be run on-prem for us.  Think of us as a ship.  Internet is sketchy at best.

Comment: unfortunately there isn't an azure alternative to Luis ai locally. Azure products are mostly cloud based, some include emulators allowing you to test and run services locally but Luis.ai doesn't.

Comment: Thanks  for the info Adam.